# JQuery-UI - help needed with draggable and droppable interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am learning JQuery & JqueryUI by building a simple shopping list APP.

I have two sections , one is to capture the user input and create a list in the "**TO-DO**" section and the other is the "**purchased**" section where the user can drop the shopped items ("from the 'TO-DO' section") by dragging them.

I have a problem with dragging the elements from the "to-do" section and  dropping the elements onto the "Purchased" section.*I tried using the "drop" event handler to look for an acceptable "droppable item" and Append it to the Purchased section* . while debugging the element gets appended to the purchased list (as I see it in the chrome debugger) with display:none  but eventually gets added in the "TO-DO" section itself .please help me implement this functionality
of dropping them in the purchased section and dragging and dropping the purchased section in the to-do section

here is the Code snippet related to the drop functionality

```js
$(function(){
 var $donediv = $(".donediv");
 var $todo = $('#todolist');
 var $donelist = $('#donelist');

 var $todoItem = $( ".todoitem" );
 var $purchaseditem = $(".purchaseditem");
 
 $todo.sortable({
  revert:true
 });
    
    $todoItem.draggable({
      connectToSortable: "#todolist",
      containment: parent,
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true,
    });

    $purchaseditem.draggable({
     containment:parent,
     cursor: 'move'
    });

    $donelist.droppable({
     accept: '#todolist > li',
     activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
     drop: function(event, ui){
            alert(ui.draggable);
      dropItem(ui.draggable);
     } 
    });

    function dropItem($item){
     //console.log($item);
     $item.fadeOut(function(){
      //console.log($("li", "#donelist"));
      $item.removeClass('todoitem').addClass('purchaseditem');
      $list = $("#donelist");
      $list.append($item);
      alert("dropped");
            $item..appendTo($list);
      /*$item.appendTo($list).fadeIn(function(){
       $item.css("background-color", "#FF5555")
      });*/
     });
    }
    
});
```

:

This is the js Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sivajs/hudqfrfz/7/

please guide me how to implement this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a demo for trying to use lists, then connect them through `ui-sortable`, using [connected lists](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists).

I may not solve the error with your code. However this way is much easy to drag and drop elements from both sections. I think it's deserved to take a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/gui47/hudqfrfz/10/

Comment: Thanks a Lot! .it worked well as i  intended ..that was really helpful! :)

Comment: @sivaJS Glad it helps. Please mark it as solution if it works with you.